# SwiftUI - "Expected expression in container literal"

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm new to swift and Xcode but I was wondering what's wrong with my code? I entered the code shown below and I get the error message, "Expected expression in container literal". Thanks in advance for your help.

```
.background(
   LinearGradient(
      gradient: Gradient(colors: [
          Color("ColourBlueberryLight"), Color("ColourBlueberryDark"),)]),
      startPoint: .top, 
      endPoint: .bottom)
)
```

Comment: The `)` after the comma that is after the second color should not be there

Comment: There is an extra `,)` right after `Color("ColourBlueberryDark")` that needs to be removed.

Comment: @Sam_M actually the `,` is fine and will compile. Just not very good looking

Comment: @aheze That is indeed correct. The `,` is just personal preference :)

Comment: I think you just learned the value of proper code formatting :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be careful where you put your parentheses and commas. Here is the fixed code:

```
LinearGradient(
    gradient: Gradient(colors: [
        Color("ColourBlueberryLight"), Color("ColourBlueberryDark") /// you had an extra ) here
    ]),
    startPoint: .top,
    endPoint: .bottom
)
```

Result:

[image: Blue gradient from top to bottom]